# Is there a simple way to assign a number to a variable?

Tags: python

```
current_points = 0
points = 0

aliens = ['r','g','b','r','g','b','b']

red_aliens = ['r']
blue_aliens = ['b']
green_aliens = ['g']

#I want to assign a number to a letter

for alien in aliens:
    if alien in red_aliens:
        (points+5) 
    if alien in blue_aliens:
        (points+20)
    if alien in green_aliens:
        (points+10)

#checking if points work    
print(points)
```

And how would I go about printing the total number of points for, let's say, a  red alien? I haven't tried that because I am stuck with the first part.

Comment: Try `point += 5` it'll update `points`

Answer (score 2):

`points + 5` is an *expression*. It doesn't change the value of any variable*.

To change the value of a variable you need an *assignment statement*, for example:

```
points = points + 5
```

For a short-hand, this will also work**:

```
points += 5
```

- *note that behind the scenes, `points + 5` is equivalent to the method call `points.__add__(5)`, which might end up *mutating* points depending on the implementation of it. Integers are immutable so the value of `points` is not modified by this method call.
- **note that behind the scenes, `points += 5` is equivalent to **either** `points = points + 5` **or** `points.__iadd__(5)`, depending on whether `__iadd__` is defined for `points`. This allows some object implementations to define `+=` as a mutation on the object instead of adding and a re-assignment.

---

To print points just for say red aliens then you can keep track of another variable:

```
red_alien_points = 0
```

Then:

```
if alien in red_aliens:
    points += 5
    red_alien_points += 5
```